# Including background image with CID

Tags: html, background-image

I need to embedd an image into an HTML mail. The image itself is already working and embedded into the mail as it is supposed to but there is one problem:
The pic is shown via : `<img src="cid:cidname" width="550" height="95" />`
but not with:

```
<div id="head" style="width:550px; height:95px; margin-bottom:0px; background-image:url(cid:cidname); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Anyone got an idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: Would you happen to be using a recent Microsoft email client?  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ suggests `background-image` is not supported in the latest versions of Outlook and Hotmail.

Comment: Im currently testing with Thunderbird v.11.0.1. Already had a look at this, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well since i needed it until today i just used <img src="..."></img> for now, buf if someone has an idead, im still happy to hear about it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is right. Or at least that's the method supported by many mail clients to use embedded images into the CSS "background-image" attribute.

However, if you're testing this in Mozilla Thunderbird , you won't be able able to watch the images because of an historical bug or lack of support for this feature. There is a bug report opened here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254015#c21 .

If you're interested on this feature, I recommend you to vote for it. It has almost passed 10 years since it was opened :/ .

Comment: I don't get it how such obvious bugs are carried along for that long … Is there any workaround / best practice for Thunderbird? I've incuded it with the table background attribute but those backgrounds seems to get lost when answering or forwarding …

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  I want this to work too. So tired of microshaft blocking images. Actually this bug is 19 years old now!  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154836